# Qlikview "Aggr" function equivalent in Microstrategy

Tags: qlikview, microstrategy

I'm trying to replicate the Qlikview Aggr function in microstrategy.  I have the Qlikview code below, and what I think is the equivalent sql translation.  The fields would be attributes in my data set.  The idea is if you select a value from a filter in the dashboard it filters "where" clause in the metric.  Is there a way to build parameters in to metrics in microstrategy?  Or does anyone have a suggestion how to build an equivalent metric?  I'm really scratching my head on the subquery part, I don't know if I could build that  as a fact, and then build a metric from it?

```
Qlikview:

Max({<Field1=>} Aggr(Sum({<Field2={'Value1'},Field3={'Value2'}, Field1=>} ThingCount), Field1))






SQL Equivalent:

select 
Max(Value)
    from(
    select Sum(case when Field2 in ('Value1') 
                            and Field3 in ('Value2') 
                            and Field1 is not NULL 
                    then ThingCount end) as Value, 
    Field1
    from Table 
    where Field1 = "FilterValue"
    group by Field1
    )a
```

Answer (score 0):

To obtain the SQL that you want you should build two metrics in MSTR:

- one that calculates the SUM, with a case (actually I would put the case in the fact definition).
- a second metric (a level metric) will calculate the MAX ignoring the Field1 attribute.

The where condition is just a selector in a MSTR document/dashboard.

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me.  The fact and the first metric that you describe would be multi-valued.  It would return two fields: Value and field1, and those two fields would have multiple values.  Is that possible in microstrategy?

Comment: What I described will return (more or less) the query you asked for. In MicroStrategy a metric is a calculation on top of a fact (which should be a numeric column in your fact table), Field1 will be an attribute in MicroStrategy. I cannot help you more from here, you should find someone who can help you to understand better MSTR or show you how to solve this problem